# Determining if a certain sequence is eventually increasing

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality

Let $0< r <1$ be a real number. For any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let $k_n \in \{0, 1, \ldots, n-1\}$ be maximal such that $$r-\frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{k_n}{n} \leq r+  \frac{1}{n}.$$ Is it true that there is some $N$ such that for any $m\geq N$, $k_{m+1} > k_m$?

UPDATE: As Melody has shown, this is not true. However, is it possible to choose the $_$ in a different way so that the sequence is eventually strictly increasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, why not look at a particular case, say $r=1/2?$ Then we have
$$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{k_n}{n}\leq \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$\frac{n-2}{2n}\leq\frac{k_n}{n}\leq\frac{n+2}{2n}$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$\frac{n-2}{2}\leq k_n\leq\frac{n+2}{2}.$$
Now suppose that $n>2$ is even, then
$$\frac{n+2}{2}\in\{0,1,...,n-1\},$$
so $k_n=(n+2)/2.$ Now we consider an $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$\frac{(n+1)-2}{2}=\frac{n-2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\leq m\leq\frac{n+2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{(n+1)+2}{2}.$$
Then $m\leq(n+2)/2$ as $(n+2)/2\in\mathbb{Z}$ and there are no integers in
$$\left(\frac{n+2}{2},\frac{n+2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right).$$
But then $k_{n+1}=(n+2)/2$ as it is maximal, hence $k_{n+1}=k_n$ and the sequence is note eventually strictly increasing.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to choose the $k_n$ in a different way so that the sequence is eventually strictly increasing?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 no, and sorry for all the deleted messages (I keep hitting enter instead of shift enter). 

Consider that
$$\frac{n-2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\leq k_{n+1}\leq\frac{n+2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$$
and
$$\frac{n-2}{2}\leq k_n\leq\frac{n+2}{2}$$
require us to have 
$$k_{n-2},k_{n-2},k_n,k_{n+1}\in\left\{\frac{n-4}{2},\frac{n-2}{2},\frac{n}{2},\frac{n+2}{2}\right\}$$
for $n$ even, so we must have
$$k_{n-1}=\frac{n-2}{2},$$
$$k_{n+1}=\frac{n+2}{2}.$$
But then applying the same argument to $n+2$ we require that
$k_{n+1}=\frac{n}{2}.$
This is a contradiction.

Comment: Your answer can be generalized to any $r\in (0,1)$, in the sense that for any such $r$, the sequence $(k_n)$ will be eventually increasing but not eventually strictly increasing, correct?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 I haven't looked it formally, but I believe so. We can always write $r$ as $1/\alpha$ for some $\alpha.$ Applying the same argument gets us a range of $k_n$ of and $k_{n+1}$ that differ by $1/\alpha$ (instead of $1/2$). So intuitively it looks like it'll generalize.